# Sharepoint 2013 Enterprise, On Premise - Content different for different users with same permissions

Tags: sharepoint

Ok, I am in the dangerous place of knowing enough to cause trouble but not enough to do things correctly; and yet still have to be the one who does the work.

When I edit a sharepoint site, I see one thing, users see something else.

- I have SP2013 Enterprise, On premise, SQL 2012.
- I have configured Excel Services, Analysis Services - and they work
- I developed an excel workbook with PowerPivot and deployed to a Sharepoint site via Excel WebPart
- Permissions are set correctly as users have to login to open the site

However...
When other users go to the site, they don't see the information I posted, they only see the default screen. By default it looks like a business intelligence site before I added anything.
In short - the content I have put on my SP site is not being seen by anyone else. WTF do I do now???
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Did you perform a check-in of your page ?
- If publication feature is enabled, did you publish the page ?

A page has to be "checked in" for others to see your modifications.
And if publishing is enabled, it should be published.

If the content of your page references other sharepoint content (file,page,...) they should be checked-in also to be visible to others.

Comment: That did it, thanks!  I couldn't seem to check in from the ribbon, but discovered that you need Stop Editing (on the ribbon) then to go to Site Contents>Page and click on the ... next to the page name and you can check it in.  Rookie mistake I know, but MANY THANKS for the help!